# Annotated die photo of 3D graphics chip

Tags: graphics, chip

I'm interested in how graphics hardware has worked at different tech levels. Having looked at [an annotated die photo of the VIC-II](http://www.mayhem64.co.uk/c64design2.jpg) for example, I now feel I have a much better understanding of how it actually works.

Is there such a photo available of a 3D graphics chip? Specifically, I'm talking about the era from the mid-nineties through the noughts, after true 3D graphics started getting hardware acceleration, and before the GPGPU, so one of the graphics chips from the fifth or sixth generation consoles, or some contemporary PC chip like the GeForce 256.

Comment: Does this count? https://wccftech.com/nvidia-gtx-1080-gp104-die-shot/ - the much higher transistor counts do mean that it's going to be less detailed.

Comment: @pjc50 That is very interesting, thanks! I might someday understand it, if I work my way up through the fifth and sixth generations first :)

Comment: Nvidia do put out a lot of architecture papers, which help understanding - really the important change is from fixed function pipelines to the shader model.

Comment: @pjc50 Right, one of the things I'm interested in understanding is what that change entails. Do you have any references to hand, to something that would explain that to a nonspecialist?